# Trying to figure out how to use getline() to read items into a file: One way works but does not the other

Tags: c++

Please check the area located in the middle of the code that states: This is the area I am struggling in. I am just confused to how I can do it for the For_Struggling.txt. It would help a lot if I can use getline(), I just keep on getting: ADTExample.cpp:57:10: error: no matching function for call to 'getline'

on the terminal! Any help would be great!

For_Struggling.txt file:   46500, Banana, 0.50

Non_Struggling.txt file:   46500 Banana 0.50 (this is for the blocked out)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector> //We need this to store things in
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Item {
    int SKU;
    string name;
    float price;
};

void printItem(Item item);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Make sure the user is using the program correctly
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Incorrect argument count.\nUsage ./a.out <input_filename>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }




    ifstream listFile;
    listFile.open(argv[1]); //Used the command line argument filename to open the file
    //If the file didn't open correctly, print an error message and terminate
    if (!listFile.good())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file: " << argv[1] << endl << "Is it in the correct directory?" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


//////////////////////This is the area I am struggling in //////////////////


    //Read the items into the file
    vector<Item> itemVector;
    while (true)
    {
        Item temp; //Item to read into
        int read_line; 
        ifstream listFile;
        //trying to figure out if I can read it this way 

       listFile >>  getline(listFile, temp.SKU,  ',') >> getline(listFile, temp.name, ',') >> getline(listFile, temp.price); 
        //Read the line

        // It works this way ------>>>> listFile >> temp.SKU >> temp.name >> temp.price;

//Why doesn't the the other way work? 


        if (listFile.eof()) //If we're at the end of file, stop reading
            break;
        itemVector.push_back(temp); //Puts the item at the end of the vector
    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Print all of the items that we read and how many we read
    cout << "Read " << itemVector.size() << " items!" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemVector.size(); i++)
        printItem(itemVector[i]);

    listFile.close();
    return 0;
}

    //Prints the members of the given struct
    void printItem(Item item)
    {
        cout << "SKU: " << item.SKU << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << item.name << endl;
        cout << "Price: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << item.price << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: First, `getline` can only read strings, but not `int` or `float`. If you insist on using `getline`, you'd have to read a string and then convert it to the desired type, e.g. with `std::stoi` and `std::stof`. Second, you don't use `getline` with `>>` - just write `getline(listFile, stringVariable, separator);`  as its own statement, not like `listFile>>getline(...)`

Comment: Why are you mixing the stream extraction operator `>>` and getline? Do either a formatted extraction (you'll need to write an `operator>>` overload for your Item type), _or_ getline. And read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). And possibly get a better textbook.

Comment: Also, your loop has a local `listFile` variable that is shadowing the `listFile` variable opened outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line of code you are trying to use multiple functonalities of std::istream at once:

- the right shift operator (">>") on the std::istream instances works as if you are pushing something from the given std::istream to the right side variable;
- std::getline is reading from the given std::istream and returning a std::istream;

```
listFile >>  getline(listFile, temp.SKU,  ',') >> getline(listFile, temp.name, ',') >> getline(listFile, temp.price);
```

as written here you are trying to write something read from the file into a std::ifstream (or, to be more specific into a std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>&, which is the return type of std::geline according to the [cppreference page for std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) );

just doing:

```
std::getline(listFile, temp.SKU,  ',');
std::getline(listFile, temp.name, ',');
std::getline(listFile, temp.price);
```

should do the job;

or, if you prefer, as a "std::istream" method, the correct usage for it would have been:

```
char* charBuffer;
long long desiredStreamSize = 100;
char delim  = ',';

int myProperty;

listFile.getline(charBuffer, desiredStreamSize, delim);

myProperty = std::stoi(charBuffer);
```

in the example of an integer property.

Answer (score 0):

Basically , `getline` is a function to take a line and give em output at `std::string`
e.g.

```
std::string word;
getline(std::cin,word);
```

Here's the solution to use getline from a file for your case,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct Item {
    int SKU;
    std::string name;
    float price;
};

int main(){
    // put your filename at file.txt
    // 46500, Banana, 0.50
    Item item;
    std::ifstream file("file.txt"); 
    std::string temp;
    getline(file,temp,',');
    item.SKU = std::stoi(temp); // change from string to integer
    getline(file,item.name,','); // no need to change anything since its the same
    getline(file,temp);
    item.price = std::stod(temp); // change from string to double/float

    std::cout << item.SKU << std::endl;
    std::cout << item.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << item.price << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
46500
 Banana
0.5
```